# Post doc or Lecturer after Full-time PhD? and Can I apply for Post doc after Thesis submission or should wait until Viva-voce?

Tags: phd, postdocs, lecturer

I am a Full-Time research scholar in finance about to submit my thesis in a month or two.

After this is it good to go for post-doc or as a lecturer in finance?

If I apply for lecturer will colleges entertain it as I am a fresher?

And one more doubt I got is, Am I eligible to apply for Post-doc position after submitting my thesis? or should I wait until the completion of Vivo-voce and/or graduation? Because its time-consuming process to receive Vivo-voce.

Kindly give your valuable suggestions

Comment: I got my PostDoc position several months before I submitted, and started 3 weeks after. However, rules and conventions differ between fields and countries, and in some countries you can start a PostDoc position before you are officially confirmed as a PhD but they will pay you less until you do get it. It would help, therefore, if you could specify where you are applying.

Comment: Please limit your post to a single question at a time. Keep in mind that the 2nd part of your post (when to apply for post-doc positions) is already answered in a different question. The first part ("apply for lecturer"), on the other hand, is hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

> After [submitting my thesis] is it good to go for post-doc or as a lecturer...?

I believe there's a **personal aspect** to consider when making this decision. In particular, do you want to work for a single institute or multiple institutes during the next 3-5 years?

> If I apply for lecturer will colleges entertain it as I am a fresher?

I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean "will colleges entertain the idea of hiring a fresh graduate?", then *yes*.

> Am I eligible to apply for Post-doc position after submitting my thesis?

**Yes** for many institutions, but there might well exist some institutes that won't hire you.

> or should I wait until the completion of Vivo-voce and/or graduation?

You'll submit your thesis in "a month or two," you'll then have to wait 3-6 months for your Vivo-voce and up to a further 6-12 months for your graduation. 
I suspect you cannot afford to wait for your Vivo-voce or graduation, **apply now** (you needn't wait until you've submitted).

Comment: Based on my experience in Europe, I would say it is unlikely you will be able to get a lecturer position in any decent or mediocre university with Just a PhD unless they are desperate or you have a 'strong' connection. 
You maybe able to obtain a teaching only position if you have experience. It may be more prudent to go for a PostDoc but also try to apply for funding as a Co-PI while doing a post doc (your own project). Gaining funding will set you apart in academia. The more money the better.